# For how much energy does the heat generated in earth's interior account in earth's total energy budget?

Tags: energy, earth, sun

I imagine the sources of earth's total energy budget to be

1. The sun

   The sun deposits about $\sim 1400 \frac{\mathrm{kW}}{\mathrm{m^2}}$ via radiation on earth[$^1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant). Eventually, this is the source of the energy of all fossil fuels and what not. Plants grow due to photosynthesis (which needs sun's energy) $\rightarrow$ we eat plants $\rightarrow$ we can do work. And so on..
2. Earth's interior

   The earth's core is warm. I imagine this due to what I call *primordial heat*, i.e. heat generated at earth's formation (e.g. due to translation of kinetic energy from meteor impacts and so on) and due to heat from decay of radioactive isotopes in earth's core and mantle (and crust).
3. Cosmic sources

   Neutrinos, cosmic rays, gravitational waves, etc. all deposit energy in earth's atmosphere and earth itself, but I imagine those negligible.

How does the total budget look like? For how much of the total energy on earth accumulated over it's lifetime does the sun account? For how much the earth itself? I want to form a statement like

*"Everything what happens and what is on earth exists solely because of the sun... except like the $\sim 1 \%$ of energy from the earth itself."*

Comment: I'm pretty sure The Internet can handle this question (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_energy_budget). I'll just say: I think we can ignore neutrino heating (maybe it's 1 kW?).